# Bash how to detect missing mandatory arguments passed to a script

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script and I need to pass a certain number of arguments to make it work.
`./upload.sh $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3`
Let's say that the 2 mandatory fields are ARG1 and ARG2, and
ARG1 and 3 are not empty.

I think the script will run and think that it has the 2 mandatory arguments, 
Is there a way to detect that ARG2 is missing/empty? 
I need to return exit 1 and not exit 0.

Here's a bit of the script

```
RESOURCE=$1
CONTAINER=$2
APP_NAME=$3

if [[ -z $RESOURCE || -z $CONTAINER ]];
then
    echo `date`" - Missing mandatory arguments: resource and container. "
    echo `date`" - Usage: ./upload.sh  [resource] [container] [appname] . "
    exit 1
fi
```

Thanks in advance,

Alain

Comment: Alain, did my answer below help?

Answer (score 11):

I like:

```
VARNAME=${1:?"missing arg 1 for VARNAME"}
```

Answer (score 7):

I always use a little function to check all the arguments:

```
process_arguments() {
    while [ -n "$1" ]
    do
        case $1 in
            -h|--help) echo "some usage details"; exit 1;;
            -x) do_something; shift; break;;
            -y) do_something_else; shift; break;;
            *) echo "some usage details"; exit 1;;
        esac
        echo $1; shift
    done
}
```

This way if you miss anything, the proper usage details will be displayed the script will exit. Otherwise, you can enter the args in any order. When your script starts, just call

```
process_arguments "$@"
```

and you should be all set.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to detect that ARG2 is missing/empty?

NO.  The way you're passing the arguments, those would be interpreted as arguments 1 and 2.

You could instead say:

```
./upload.sh "$ARG1" "$ARG2" "$ARG3"
```

in order to make bash interpret the arguments correctly whether those are empty or not.

---

Example:

```
$ cat file
[ -z $1 ] && echo "Arg 1 missing"
[ -z $2 ] && echo "Arg 2 missing"
[ -z $3 ] && echo "Arg 3 missing"
$ bash file "$HOME" "$FOOBAR" "$USER"
Arg 2 missing
```

(The variable `FOOBAR` was undefined in the above example.)

Answer (score 1):

Args as you are using them are positional so is you only provided 1 and 3, but 1 and 2 are require, you just accidentally provided a value for arg 3 as arg 2.

You could require that your optional arguments start with a dash -, and if you find either $1 or $2 start with a dash you know you are missing a required. You of course would have to remove the dash from $3.

A better way to handle args is to use [getopts](http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/1/getopts/). Here are a couple of resources to get you started:

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial
- http://rsalveti.wordpress.com/2007/04/03/bash-parsing-arguments-with-getopts/

This will allow you to handle args in a way similar to standard commandline utils. If you write commandline utils in C you have probably used the C library version of getops before.

Answer (score 0):

> I think the script will run and think that it has the 2 mandatory arguments, Is there a way to detect that ARG2 is missing/empty?

No unless `ARG2` either

- has some identifiable structure such as a URL, an email, or a bank account can have, or
- is the named of an object whose existence can be tested like a file, an entry in a file, etc.

If any of the above holds, you can write a piece of code that will determine whether `ARG2` really corresponds to a `CONTAINER` or is most likely a `APP_NAME`

If not, you will need either to

- make the third argument mandatory
- drop the use of positional arguments in favour of named arguments e.g. `./upload.sh --resource blah --container blahblah --appname blablahblah`, with the handy `getopts`.